# Mapping a set of intervals to 2D text buffer with text change synchronization

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, text

I have a 2D text-like buffer (basically `List<List<Object>>`), indexed by (row, col) coordinates. Each row can have arbitrary length.

Let `pos = (row, col)`. Then an interval is defined by `(fromPos, toPos)`.

The text buffer can be modified by inserting and deleting characters:

```
void addRow(int rowIndex, Row<T> newRow);

void removeRow(int rowIndex);

void insert(int row, int col, Collection<? extends T> els);

void delete(int row, int col, int count);
```

How do I reflect changes in the text in position of intervals?  Intervals are nested, but not strictly.

The main problem is that intervals can be empty and the ordering and nesting of intervals must be preserved.

For example:

```
0 1   2  3 4        (interval number)

[a[bcd[]][][ef]gh]  (text)

 0 123      45 67   (char index)
```

after insert of `X` in the 3rd interval (absolute position 4) should become

```
0 1   2  3  4           (interval number)

[a[bcd[]][X][ef]ghijk]  (text)
```

What are some ways to store intervals to be able to reflect changes of the text correctly and efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

I would store intervals as pairs of "cursors" and then maintain the order of the cursors in a splay tree. Rather than store the row/column of each cursor directly, I would use a difference representation. For a 1D example, to store cursors A-E with A=1, B=2, C=3, D=5, E=7, the tree might be

```
    B2
   / \
  /   \
 /     \
A-1     D3
       / \
      C-2 E2
```

Now, when inserting a character at position 4, I use the standard insertion algorithm to find the first cursors to the left, summing along the path as I descend. This is cursor C, which I splay to the top, fixing the numbers with each rotate.

```
      C3
     / \
    /   \
   /     \
  B-1     D2
 /         \
A-1         E2
```

Now I add one to C's right child. Because of the difference representation, that has the effect of incrementing the whole subtree by one.

```
      C3
     / \
    /   \
   /     \
  B-1     D3
 /         \
A-1         E2
```

The other operations are simple exercises in manipulating splay trees.